# Extra condition in ON clause is ignored

Tags: mysql, join

I have this query:

```
    SELECT
        TA.id,
        T.duration,         
        DATE_FORMAT(TA.startTime,'%H:%i') AS startTime,
        TEI.displayname,
        TA.threatment_id,
        TE.employeeid,
        TTS.appointment_date
    FROM
        tblEmployee AS TE
        INNER Join tblEmployeeInfo AS TEI ON TEI.employeeinfoid = TE.employeeinfoid
        LEFT OUTER Join tblAppointment AS TA ON TE.employeeid = TA.employee_id
        LEFT OUTER Join tblThreatment AS T ON TA.threatment_id = T.threatmentid
        LEFT OUTER Join tblAppointments AS TTS ON TTS.id = TA.appointments_id 
            AND TTS.appointment_date = '2009-10-19'
        LEFT OUTER Join tblCustomerCard AS TCC ON TCC.customercardid = TTS.customercard_id
    WHERE
        TE.employeeid = 1
```

What I try to accomplish is to select an employee, if available, all appointments at a given date. When there aren't any appointments, it should at least give the information about the employee.

But right now, it just gives all appointments related to an employee, and passes null when the date doesn't match. Whats going wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps you need ( ) around both conditions for it to evaluate both? It's worth a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are doing a left OUTER join, it will only join those records that match the On condition and will attach Null when the condition is not met.

You will still get records for which there is no Appointments on that date.

If you did an INNER join, then if the On condition is not met, no record will be output. So you will not get any records for which there are no appointments on that date.

Comment: So it's basicly not possible what i want to achieve, and have to use two distinct queries to get the information?

Comment: Yeah sorry.. just reread your original query. It might be possible, but I think logically you are trying to get two different things and so two queries would make more sense..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not sure what database you are on, but this would work on SQL server :

```
select * from tblEmployee TA
...
left join 
( select * from tblAppointments ed where ed.appointment_date = '10/01/2008' ) TTS
on  ON TTS.id = TA.appointments_id
```

Thats the vibe anyway! You might need to tinker a bit.. Im at work and cant get the whole thing going for ya! :)